# Parse Error OptimizePress 2 WP

Tags: php, plugins, web, wordpress

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'OptimizePress_Install'
>   (T_STRING) in
>   /home/investor/public_html/wp-content/themes/optimizepress/lib/admin/install.php
>   on line 1

Getting this annoying error when I click on "Activate Theme". How do I get around this? Code is below on pastebin

http://pastebin.com/GJkL64d1

Comment: you need a space in the start, change "<?phpclass OptimizePress_Install" to "<?php class OptimizePress_Install"

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: It is because the script in concated to a single line. Because of that the  // outcommenting is "washing" out everything after the first // Get the original script from where it is not one single line

Comment: Watch the videos and go through the tutorials before starting op2 from http://www.optimizehub.com/. You can also go for some youtube videos.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it needs a space between `<?php` and `class` so change it to `<?php class`

The second reason is it failing is because it is a 1 line script (all goes is on one line).
The first time it meets a comment the rest of the script is commented out.

You can fix this by

1. Download the file where is it not a strange one line.
2. Remove all comments
3. Beautify the php (make currect spaces)

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, what did you expect? Free work? Did you download the plugin from the original source and not modified it? If this is the original, stay far away from it, the code is complete legacy shit and born with errors that make it not work, would be something not to install.